# Tracking in Geofence radious

Tags: android, locationlistener, android-geofence

I have Created application for geo fence.

I implement location listener which sends me current Lat and Long.

I have array of Lat Long and i created Geofence from this array.

I want to check that Current lat long are within my Geofence Region or not?

Code For Geofence:-

```
private void createGeofence(double latitude, double longitude, int radius,
            String geofenceType, String title) {

        Marker stopMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .draggable(true)
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title(title)
                );

        googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).radius(radius)
                .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#B2A9F6")));
    }
```

Lat Long from Listener:-

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Lat=location.getLatitude();
        Lng=location.getLongitude();    

        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {

             addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Lat, Lng, 1);
             address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
             city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
             country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        System.out.println("Lat Long is "+ Lat + " " + Lng);

    }
```

Please help for  this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the harvesine formula:

```
    public static final double R = 6372.8; // In kilometers

    public static double haversine(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
      double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
      double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
      lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
      lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);

      double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
      double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
      return R * c;
    }
```

That will give you the distance between the two locations. After that you could compare that distance with the geofence region radius to know if is inside the region.

**Note: This distance will be in kilometers if your radius is on meters then just multiply the haversine method result with 1000 so that it's converted to meters.**

[Reference](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)